# 301 redirect to url without extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up my site without file extensions in the URLs.

All my pages are php.

All my menu links have extensions removed, such as...

```
<a href="page1">page 1</a>
<a href="page2">page 2</a>
<a href="page3">page 3</a>
```

And these links all work fine.

But I am trying to now set up a .htaccess file to make 301 redirects from other external links, such as Google.

In my htaccess file, I have...

```
Redirect 301 /page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
```

But this makes the link from Google hit the 404 page not found - it doesn't go to the page that it should.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get these 301 redirects to work properly?

EDIT

In an effort to try and debug this, I have changed my htaccess file. My full htaccess code is now this...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

CheckSpelling Off

FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options +FollowSymlinks

Redirect 301 https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
Redirect 301 https://mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
Redirect 301 http://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
Redirect 301 http://mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
Redirect 301 www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
```

Now if I follow the menu link, I get to...

```
https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
```

If I enter https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1 into the address bar of the browser, it loads the page correctly.

BUT if I follow the link from google, it ends up at...

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php
```

How can this be?!

I have covered all possible URLs in my htaccess file, so how does this google link go to the http:// file with the .php at the end?

Comment: What happens when you directly enter `https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1` in browser?

Comment: That also goes to the 404 page. But links from the menu work ok??

Comment: Then obviously link from menu is resolving to some other URL not this one.

Comment: What is the URL of the page that contains an anchor of the form `<a href="page1">page 1</a>` which works? Do you have a `base` element? (How are you currently appending the file extension?)

Comment: All site pages have the menu, so the page that contains the anchor could be any of the similar pages. I have added everything that is in my htaccess file to the edit on the original post.

Comment: With the htaccess as it was first, typing the URL goes to the 404 page. With the htaccess file as in the edit, it goes to the .php page. All site pages and the htaccess file are all in the same root directory.

Comment: Just to be clear, Google currently lists the http (not s) link, and it includes the .php extension. I am trying to redirect this google link to go to the https link without the .php extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are currently using Apache's `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation)  to map URLs without the file extension (eg. `/page1`) to the corresponding URL with the file extension (eg. `/page1.php`) - since you have nothing else in your `.htaccess` file that does this.

MultiViews maps file extensions using internal subrequests, so you will need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`), as opposed to mod_alias (`Redirect`) in order to redirect to the extensionless URLs, since you only want to redirect direct requests, not subrequests, and it's not possible to differentiate with `Redirect`.

> ```
> Redirect 301 https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
> Redirect 301 https://mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
> Redirect 301 http://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
> Redirect 301 http://mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
> Redirect 301 www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1
> ```

You need to change the above `Redirect` directives to something like the following. (Incidentally, the above directives aren't actually doing anything since the URL-path stated, eg. `https://www.mysite.co.uk/page1.php`, would never match - this must be a root-relative URL-path.)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we are only redirecting initial/direct requests.

Note that this is currently a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to a `301` (permanent) redirect only after you have confirmed that it's all working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.)

---

You could also try the following one-liner instead (without a `RewriteCond` directive):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NS,R=302,L]
```

Note the addition of the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag, that prevents the directive being processed for internal subrequests.

---

**UPDATE:** Try disabling `MultiViews` and doing this all with mod_rewrite instead (which is probably recommended). For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Remove .php file extension with an external redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]

# Append the .php extension with an internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.])+$ $1.php [L]
```

The directives that append the file extension assumes that existing URLs do not already include a dot. ie. dots only occur when a file extension is applied to the URL.

Comment: I tried both code examples, and tried links from Google and internal links. Now all URLs result in an error page that says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example that does not use MultiViews. This uses mod_rewrite for both redirecting (removing the `.php` file extension) and rewriting (adding it back again) the request.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This helped me a lot.